# Customize Login Page design for Authentication type : Individual User account ASP.NET core 2.1, MVC, c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to implement OAuth2.0 for my web application. I have done that following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2) link.

I have registered with 2 external providers Microsoft and Google. I have added Authentication in startup.cs file as well.

So when I run the application, click on Login button on top right corner, a Login page is displayed.The URL it is showing is `https://localhost:44325/Identity/Account/Login`.

But I'm unable to find this page anywhere in my solution. I want to modify this page's design and want to make this my first page as soon as I open the application.

[image]

How do I do it?

### Edit

[image]

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI is in the project and more than likely there is also an Area named Identity.  It isn't a singular page but a a whole lot of them that make up Identity.  Look for the Area and you will find them.

Comment: @mvermef I have seen there. Didn't find anything. I have attached the screen shot in the question for your reference.

Comment: It's the assembly I listed function, the pages are in the assembly...

Comment: @mvermef I may sound dumb here, but can you please elaborate your answer please. I do not find any folder named Assembly :|

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/aspnetcore-2-1-identity-ui/

Comment: [How to customize the login buttons #10563](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/10563)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To low to comment so I'll post as an answer, follow the instructions at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802781/where-are-the-login-and-register-pages-in-an-aspnet-core-scaffolded-app).

For me I just right-clicked on the project, selected `Add -> New Scaffold Item`, picked `Identity` on the new dialog, in the left pane, and followed the prompts.

The `login.cshtml` pages were created in the `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` directory.

Comment: 2 days of trying to figure out why I could no longer find the view models and it was just that easy. Thank you.

Just so others know, you will need to a complete clean and recompile your application, after doing this otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: It seems it can also be done through the CLI, but it's not very straightforward: https://andrewlock.net/customising-aspnetcore-identity-without-editing-the-pagemodel/