# Customize login page of ASP.NET web page without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

How can I create a new scaffold item with terminal commands, without using visual studio? I would need it for the same reason requested here:
[Customize Login Page design for Authentication type : Individual User account ASP.NET core 2.1, MVC, c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54995474/customize-login-page-design-for-authentication-type-individual-user-account-as)

but finding myself on linux I can only use dotnet commands. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands in your project directory

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet restore
```

after that

> Run the following command to list the Identity scaffolder options:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h
```

> In the project folder, run the Identity scaffolder with the options you want. For example, to setup identity with the default UI and the minimum number of files, run the following command. Use the correct fully qualified name for your DB context:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login"
```

More information can be found at [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli)