# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC How to allow the user to select his role when registering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Application. I have added "Buyer" and "Seller" roles. How can I add the option for the user to chose one of them when registering.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add code showing what you have tried? That would be incredibly helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a solution that needs some adjustments, but for the time being works for me. So here is what I did:

1. We need to scaffold the Register.cshtml file. To do that I used the instructions given by the user with the name John Rah as an answer to another question. This is a link to what he wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004931/9570978. But for your convenience, I     will write the steps here as well, though all credit goes to him.

1.1 Right click on your project name -> select "Add" -> "New Scaffolded Item".

[image: Firtst step to creating scaffolded item]

1.2 On the "Add New Scaffolded Item" tab select "Identity" (on the left side). -> In the middle of the tapp click on "Identity". -> Press "Add".
[image: Second step to adding New Scaffolded Item]
1.3 From the "Add Identity" tab check the box next to "Account/Register". -> From the "Data context class" drop down list select "ApplicationDbContext ([ProjectName].Data)". -> Click "Add".

[image: Third step to adding New Scaffolded Item]

2. Now comes the coding part. First we will edit the Register.cshtml.cs, located at [Project name]/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml

[image: Location of the file]

2.1 Firstly I added a new property to the RegisterModel class, that stores List.

```
public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; }
```

2.2 Then in the constructor I create the List.

```
Roles = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "Seller", Text ="Seller"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "Buyer", Text = "Buyer"},
        };
```

2.3 After that I added the following property to the InputModel class, located within the RegisterModel

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserRole")]
public string UserRole { get; set; }
```

2.4 The last thing I did here was editing the OnPostAsync method. In the code block checking if the creation of the user was successful

```
 if(result.Succeeded)
```

I added the following line :

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.UserRole);
```

3. The last step is to edit the Register.cshtml file, located at [Project name]/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account

3.1 Just under the code for the "ConfirmPassword" field

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
            <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

I added the code that creates the drop-down list, used by the user to chose his role

```
<div class="form-group">
            <select asp-for="Input.UserRole"
                asp-items="@(Model.Roles)">
                <option>Please select a role</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserRole" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: For .net core 6 or the latest version you will need to modify this answer pls refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/623030/assign-user-to-role-during-registration