# Modify Log in page text in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using the standard new ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Angular project template and I am trying to find the text displayed on the standard Log In page:

[image]

This is displayed at *https://localhost:xxxxx/Identity/Account/Login*

Searching all files in the solution for any text from this form returns no results and I am starting to think it's in a DLL or some other place I don't see. Is that the case?

Where can I modify that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. And it enables us to apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL), then you can modify the code and change the behavior based on your actual scenario and requirement.

[image]

For more information about "Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects", you can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

This appears to [have been moved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805403/2411713) into a Razor Class library, source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1ed72f8f5f14dfc5a4ebc9d5d116d63792caa7fc/src/Security/samples/Identity.ExternalClaims/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml).

Comment: I believe you can override the page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004931/2411713