# How to limit the maximum registered user count in asp.net core identity

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, registration

I have just created an asp.net core 3.1 project by selecting the **react** template for the ui and **individual user accounts** for the authentication. The requirement I need to meet on the open source project I have just started to work on is preventing multiple registered users. I would like to have this application should have only one registered user. So I have tried to have [the identity scaffolding item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004931/104969), but this attempt has just created only the razor files, not the controllers. According to the requirement, I think I need to access to the controllers to limit the maximum registered user count. How can I achieve that?

Thanks,

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by "each instance of this application should have only one active user" given that it is an ASP.NET project. Traditionally, a web application is meant to allow for a large number of simultaneous users. Could you expand on the requirement please so we can better target the advice?

Comment: @PeterLange updated my question, sorry for being not clear.

Comment: Why do you have such requirement? What is the real problem behind it?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Think this as a personal blog. The registered user will be the admin / owner and will provide content. And the non registered users of the system will just browse the provided content.

Comment: This is what I understood from your question, scaffold has created only razor files not the controller so you are confused where should you add logic to limit registration?

Comment: @Aakash exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it out. The logic behind the razor views is not in controllers anymore. I found it in the *Register.cshtml.cs* file.

[image]