# How to edit login page in WebAssembly project with Individual User Accounts?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor-webassembly

I have selected Individual User Accounts while creating Blazor application. I have no idea where I can modify the Login page that was created, the file with source dode is not available anywhere.

How to modify Login page in that scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When choosing your configuration the created template gets delivered with IdentityServer and ASP.NET Core Identity. IdentityServer makes the Endpoint OpenID/OAuth compatible. This is needed for the Blazor WebAssembly app to streamline the process of getting a token, validating it etc. ASP.NET Core Identity is used to save and retrieve the users from the database, loging them in by setting a Cookie and checking the correctness of provided passwords, hashing them etc. **This link answers how you can modify the default Razor Pages delivered when an app with ASP.NET Core Identity is created.**

[Where are the Login and Register pages in an AspNet Core scaffolded app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802781/where-are-the-login-and-register-pages-in-an-aspnet-core-scaffolded-app/58004931#58004931)

Comment: Not an answer. I followed few links and the csthml files are added, not razor and code doesn't compile anymore.