# Blazor server with individual accounts that uses API instead of SQL server

Tags: authentication, cookies, server, blazor

I'm trying to implement Blazor server with authentization using the premade Individual accounts code but instead of the data being verified through SQL, I need to call API first (which will then contact SQL server, for some security reasons) - the API will then verify, if the user is authenticated or not and will reply.

Where can I do the changes? Where can I set it up so that the Login event contacts API and not the database? It seems to me that most of the code is hidden and should be available via New scaffolding, yet that option is not available either.

I have tried to create a custom authentication, which succeeded partially. I was able to save the key in ProtectedLocalStorage. It is not ideal and should be saved within cookies, not Local storage. And I have failed at modifying that code to make sure that the sessionID is saved into cookies.

Comment: You are correct that code is hidden in a DLL. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802781/where-are-the-login-and-register-pages-in-an-aspnet-core-scaffolded-app) that explains it for an older version. 


I