# what is the path to login page?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, code-generation, asp.net-core-scaffolding

We added the scaffolding for identity.
We didn't override any pages.
Now I can't reach the login or register pages.

From this post
[Where are the Login and Register pages in an AspNet Core scaffolded app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802781/where-are-the-login-and-register-pages-in-an-aspnet-core-scaffolded-app)

I expect to find the Register page at

> mydomain.com/Account/Register

or

> mydomain.com/Identity/Account/Register

also tried

> mydomain.com/Identity/Register

_loginPartial.cshtml has

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
</li>
```

but that by itself isn't enough to make the links exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, correct URL would be:

```
mydomain.com/Identity/Account/Register
mydomain.com/Identity/Account/Login
```

You can check Startup.cs (Program.cs) for routing configuraton. Also if you check _LoginPartial.cshtml file, it should have exact links to register and login pages.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct and serves to highlight that I have a bigger issue. Thanks. I'll create another post with the real issue.